# Why collectionviewsource not updating the datagrid when clicking a button?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm, datagrid

I have two viewmodels one is the mainViewModel and the other is the parentViewModel. I set the mainViewModel as the data context of the grid of my mainwindow and set the parentViewModel as the data context of my datagrid. I tried using the models generated by the entity framework to update the datagrid but I'm getting an error when I'm implementing the INotifyPropertyChange, so I made a custom model and map the data from the entity framework model to my custom model.

parentViewModel:

In this case the Parent class is an entity framework generated model and the Parents class is my custom made model.

```
public class ParentViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
    #region Constructor
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of Parent ViewModel class.
    /// </summary>
    public ParentViewModel()
    {
        _addParentCommand = new AddParentCommand(AddParent, IsExecutable);
        Parentss = new Parents()
        {
            PLastName = null,
            PFirstName = null,
            PMiddleName = null,
            PAddress = null,
            PContactNo = null,
            PEmail = null,
            PUsername = null,
            PPassword = null,
            ValidationString = null
        };
        _parentCollection = new ObservableCollection<Parent>();
        _parentsCollection = new ObservableCollection<Parents>();
        //ParentsCollection = new ObservableCollection<Parents>();
        _parentList = new List<Parent>();
        _parentsList = new List<Parents>();
        ViewSource = new CollectionViewSource();
        ViewSource.Source = ParentsCollection;
        Load();
    }
    #endregion

    #region Events
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Methods
    /// <summary>
    /// Checks if the application can execute a method.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context">Data context</param>
    /// <returns>bool</returns>
    public bool IsExecutable(object context)
    {
        if (context != null)
        {
            var s = context as string;
            s = s.Trim();
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Loads the data from the database when the application starts.
    /// </summary>
    public void Load()
    {
        using (RegistrationEntities registrationContext = new RegistrationEntities())
        {
            _parentList = registrationContext.Parents.ToList();


            for (int i = 0; i < _parentList.Count; i++)
            {
                Parents = new Parents()
                {
                    PId = _parentList[i].P_Id,
                    PLastName = _parentList[i].P_LastName,
                    PFirstName = _parentList[i].P_FirstName,
                    PMiddleName = _parentList[i].P_MiddleName,
                    PAddress = _parentList[i].P_Address,
                    PContactNo = _parentList[i].P_ContactNo,
                    PEmail = _parentList[i].P_Email,
                    PUsername = _parentList[i].P_Username,
                    PPassword = _parentList[i].P_Password,
                    PCreatedOn = _parentList[i].P_CreatedOn,
                    PUpdatedAt = _parentList[i].P_UpdatedAt
                };

                _parentsCollection.Add(Parents);
                //ParentsCollection.Add(Parents);
            }
        }
    }

    public void Load2()
    {
        //for (int i = 0; i < _parentsList.Count; i++)
        //{
        //    _parentsCollection.Add(_parentsList[i]);
        //}
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Add a new Parent.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context">Data context</param>
    public void AddParent(object context)
    {
        using (RegistrationEntities registrationContext = new RegistrationEntities())
        {
            Parent parent = new Parent
            {
                P_LastName = Parentss.PLastName,
                P_FirstName = Parentss.PFirstName,
                P_MiddleName = Parentss.PMiddleName,
                P_Address = Parentss.PAddress,
                P_ContactNo = Parentss.PContactNo,
                P_Email = Parentss.PEmail,
                P_Username = Parentss.PUsername,
                P_Password = Encrypt(Parentss.PPassword),
                P_CreatedOn = DateTime.Now.Date + DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay,
                P_UpdatedAt = DateTime.Now.Date + DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay
            };

            registrationContext.Parents.Add(parent);

            try
            {
                registrationContext.SaveChanges();

                _parentList = registrationContext.Parents.ToList();

                _parentsCollection.Clear();
                //ParentsCollection.Clear();

                for (int i = 0; i < _parentList.Count; i++)
                {
                    Parents = new Parents()
                    {
                        PId = _parentList[i].P_Id,
                        PLastName = _parentList[i].P_LastName,
                        PFirstName = _parentList[i].P_FirstName,
                        PMiddleName = _parentList[i].P_MiddleName,
                        PAddress = _parentList[i].P_Address,
                        PContactNo = _parentList[i].P_ContactNo,
                        PEmail = _parentList[i].P_Email,
                        PUsername = _parentList[i].P_Username,
                        PPassword = _parentList[i].P_Password,
                        PCreatedOn = _parentList[i].P_CreatedOn,
                        PUpdatedAt = _parentList[i].P_UpdatedAt
                    };

                    _parentsCollection.Add(Parents);
                     ViewSource.View.Refresh();
                    //ParentsCollection.Add(Parents);

                }

                MessageBox.Show("Success!");

                Parentss.PLastName = null;
                Parentss.PFirstName = null;
                Parentss.PMiddleName = null;
                Parentss.PAddress = null;
                Parentss.PContactNo = null;
                Parentss.PEmail = null;
                Parentss.PUsername = null;
                Parentss.PPassword = null;
            }
            catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
            {
                foreach (var eve in ex.EntityValidationErrors)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Entity of type \"{0}\" in state \"{1}\" has the following validation errors: ", eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name, eve.Entry.State));
                    foreach (var ve in eve.ValidationErrors)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("- Property: \"{0}\", Value: \"{1}\", Error: \"{2}\"", ve.PropertyName, eve.Entry.CurrentValues.GetValue<object>(ve.PropertyName), ve.ErrorMessage));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public string Encrypt(string password)
    {
        MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
        md5.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(password));
        byte[] result = md5.Hash;
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
        {
            str.Append(result[i].ToString("x2"));
        }

        return str.ToString();
    }
    #endregion

    #region Commands and Properties
    private ICommand _addParentCommand;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets an ICommand interface.
    /// </summary>
    public ICommand AddParentCommand
    {
        get { return _addParentCommand; }
        set { _addParentCommand = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a Parent class.
    /// </summary>
    public Parents Parentss
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public Parents Parents
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    private List<Parent> _parentList;

    public List<Parent> ParentList
    {
        get { return _parentList; }
        set { _parentList = value; OnPropertyChanged("ParentList"); }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Parent> _parentCollection;

    public ObservableCollection<Parent> ParentCollection
    {
        get { return _parentCollection; }
        set { _parentCollection = value; }
    }

    private List<Parents> _parentsList;

    public List<Parents> ParentsList
    {
        get { return _parentsList; }
        set { _parentsList = value; }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Parents> _parentsCollection;

    public ObservableCollection<Parents> ParentsCollection
    {
        get { return _parentsCollection; }
        set { _parentsCollection = value; }
    }

    public CollectionViewSource ViewSource { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

XAML:

```
 <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource mainViewModel}">

<DataGrid x:Name="dgvParent" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" SelectionMode="Single" BorderThickness="2" Style="{StaticResource AzureDataGrid}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AlternatingRowBackground="LightBlue" ItemsSource="{Binding ViewSource.View}" DataContext="{DynamicResource parentViewModel}" CanUserAddRows="False">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding PId}" FontWeight="Bold" Header="Id" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding PLastName}" FontWeight="Bold" Header="Last Name" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding PFirstName}" FontWeight="Bold" Header="First Name" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding PMiddleName}" FontWeight="Bold" Header="Middle Name" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding PAddress}" FontWeight="Bold" Header="Address" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding PContactNo}" FontWeight="Bold" Header="Contact Number" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding PEmail}" FontWeight="Bold" Header="Email" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding PCreatedOn}" FontWeight="Bold" Header="Created On" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding PUpdatedAt}" FontWeight="Bold" Header="Updated At" />
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

that is what i do in my projects:

```
public ICollectionView MyView{ get; set; }

//ctor
public ParentViewModel()
{
    //...
    ParentsCollection= new ObservableCollection<Parents>();
    MyView= CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(ParentsCollection);
    //...
}


<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyView}"/>
```

btw. if you Bindings not work check the **DataContext** and **BindingExpressions** at runtime with Snoop. Its **ALWAYS** one of the two ;)

Answer (score -1):

My answer is not really an answer -- more like a series of complaints and recommendations -- but it doesn't fit into a comments box so I'm placing it here.

1. There's a lot of room for cleanup and improvement here, especially when it comes to your variable names and multiple similar-looking variable definitions.
2. It doesn't look like you've included the button definition, so we have no idea if your `AddParentCommand` is being executed.
3. Having an `ObservableCollection` is pointless if you're going to completely clear and rebuild the collection each time; you could just leave it as a `List` and notify property changed for the list, but properly harnessing the power of `ObservableCollection` would be better.
4. I do not believe your `CollectionViewSource` is gaining you anything except maybe helping you recover from the fact that you're not actually raising `PropertyChanged` on your properties.

Try getting a simpler version of your code to work first without the DB persistence.

Comment: -1 for 3. because its the nice thing of ObservableCollection -> just create the instance ONCE und use Clear(), Add(), Remove() to alter it. If you use ICollectionView for Sorting, Filtering and Navigation then its even more easier to just create the instance once. otherwise you need to recreate the ICollectionView every time you create a new instance of ObservableCollection

Comment: @blindmeis I'm just pointing out the fact that calling `Clear` and rebuilding the `ObservableCollection` from scratch seems less than ideal as opposed to just calling `Add` and `Remove` as needed. I honestly think we're on the same page here and the -1 is unwarranted. I'm not actually suggesting to use a `List` instead of `ObservableCollection` but that's more or less what OP has accomplished with this code.